# Minimizing $a^TPa$ (for arbitrary $a$) vs minimizing trace$(P)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, kalman-filter

**Context**: I am reading "Introduction to stochastic control theory"
by Karl Johan Åström. There he develops a Kalman filter with the goal of "minimizing $a^TPa$ for arbitrary vector $a$", where $P$ is the resulting covariance matrix of the filter. Surprisingly, the result doesn't depend on the vector $a$. Moreover, I have seen other papers/notes in which they develop the exact same result, but by minimizing trace$(P)$ instead, without mentioning any "arbitrary vector $a$".

**Question**: This confuses me. Is minimizing $a^TPa$ (for arbitrary $a$) somehow the same as minimizing trace$(P)$? What does "arbitrary $a$" mean anyway in this context?

Comment: It means Any vector $a$

Comment: Oh, for sure. But how does one minimize $a^TPa$ for some arbitrary $a$? Is that: optimize $a^TPa$ for all $a$?  Meaning that we expect the optimal P to be the same for an infinite amount of cost functions?

Comment: It can also be noted that if $P=\mathbb{E}\!\left((x-\mathbb{E}(x))\,(x-\mathbb{E}(x))^\top\right)$ than that $\text{trace}(P)=\mathbb{E}\!\left((x-\mathbb{E}(x))^\top (x-\mathbb{E}(x))\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, minimizing $\text{trace}(P) = \sum_i P_{ii}$ is the same as minimizing $a^TPa$ for an arbitrary vector $a \neq 0$ because $P$ is symmetric (it is a covariance matrix) and so it can be diagonalized. That is, there exist matrices $D, V$ such that $P = VDV^T$, where $D = \text{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n)$. Since the trace operator is invariant under a change of basis and $a^TPa = a^TVDV^Ta=b^TDb=\sum_i b_i^2d_i$, minimizing the last term is the same as minimizing the trace because $b_i^2 > 0$.

Comment: Nice! Can you elaborate in the last part? Why minimizing that last term is the same as minimizing the trace? I get the intuition but I do not seem to be able to show it formally. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $d_i > 0$ because $P$ is positive-definite. It is easy to proof that for positive constants $c_1, \ldots, c_n$, the minimum of $\sum_i c_ix_i$ is attained at the same values of $x_i$ that the minimum of $\sum_i x_i$, if $x_i$ are constrained to be non-negative.

Comment: I think I get that. However, preciselly that "easy" part is the part where I'm struggling. I'll mark the answer as correct anyway. Thanks sir!